# Extend nested SASS selector inside another SASS file

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, oocss

I am looking for a way to reduce the repetition in my SASS. I have the following declaration, which is nested inside a selector.

Inside `register.scss`:

```
        .btn-primary {
            background-color: $brand-btn-primary;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 24px;
        }
```

I would like to `@extend` that inside the selector in another SASS file but i'm unsure if that's possible.

`admin.scss`:

```
    .btn-primary.upgrade-btn {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        background-color: $brand-btn-primary;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 24px;
        border: 1px solid $brand-btn-primary;
        min-width: 160px;
    }
```

When I have attempted this I get the following error:

> Error: complex selectors may not be extended.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: just add both classes to the div, and dont try to extend .btn-primary.upgrade-btn, just use .upgrade-btn.. If you import them correctly, specificity of CSS will do the rest

Comment: Sadly it's not that easy. The `btn-primary` in the register file is already overriding the default declaration, so I need to extend the overridden declaration.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the @extend?

Comment: @djnetherton I am looking to `extend` the CSS declarations in `.btn-primary` inside the `.btn-primary.upgrade-btn` definition in the code block above. As you can see they share the same attributes and i'd rather extend rather than duplicate this in my SASS. Is this possible? Or does the selector need to be in the same file and not nested?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove the double class selector and extend using the method below.

```
.btn-primary {
  background-color: $brand-btn-primary;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.upgrade-btn {
  @extend .btn-primary;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  border: 1px solid $brand-btn-primary;
  min-width: 160px;
}
```